# i have problem in style with CKEDITOR 4.6.2

Tags: html, css

I used a border in td, but it disappeared, how can I make it have the border?

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%;border:1px black solid;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">

                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width:50%;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `td` does not have a border because it is empty. Fill it with content and you'll see the border starts appearing.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;border:1px black solid;">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
        I am in the inner table
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;">I am in the outer table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```